# Duplicate data when I merge Firestore queries

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My backend is built on Firestore and there's no logical `OR` to build my queries and so to fix this I'm using multiple queries and merging them to simulate a logical `OR`, query request and merge works perfectly, but now there's another problem I get duplicate data, and so to fix this I decided to create a `HashSet` and store my objects in it, but I still get duplicate data in a hashset

Here's how I merge queries:

```
    Tasks.whenAllSuccess(c).addOnSuccessListener(new BaseValueOnSuccessListener(mapper, firebaseCallback));
```

c is a collections of Task

and here's how I store my data (in my custom BaseValueOnSuccessListener listener): Please check my OnSuccess method

```
public class BaseValueOnSuccessListener<Model, Entity> implements OnSuccessListener<List<QuerySnapshot>> {
    private FirebaseMapper<Entity, Model> mapper;
    // FirebaseDatabaseRepositoryCallback is an interface
    private FirebaseDatabaseRepository.FirebaseDatabaseRepositoryCallback<Model> callback;

    public BaseValueOnSuccessListener(FirebaseMapper<Entity, Model> mapper,
                                      FirebaseDatabaseRepository.FirebaseDatabaseRepositoryCallback<Model> callback) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.callback = callback;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshots) {
        // Do what you need to do with your list
        if (!querySnapshots.isEmpty()) {
            // List<Model> data = new ArrayList<>();
            Set<Model> data = new HashSet<>();
            for (QuerySnapshot querySnapshot : querySnapshots) {
                data.addAll(mapper.mapList(querySnapshot));
            }
            callback.onSuccess(new ArrayList<Model>(data));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now there's another problem I get duplicate data, and so to fix this I decided to create a hashset and store my objects in it, but I still get duplicate data in a hashset

You are getting duplicate data because you are adding in your `Set`, different objects of type `Model`. Every `Model` object in your in set has a different address in the memory and that's why every object within your set is different. The `Set` is an interface which extends Collection, so when using such a collection, you cannot know if a field within an object holds the same value as another filed within another object, unless you specify it.

There is a big difference between a `Set` and a `List`. If you are using:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("user2426691");
list.add("user2426691");
list.add("user2426691");
Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
```

You'll see that your list will contains three duplicate names. However, if you would have used a `Set` of strings like in the following lines of code:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list);
Log.d(TAG, set.toString());
```

You would have been noticed that the your `Set` will contain only one element (no duplicates).

To solve your problem, you can either use a `List` or a `Set` but you need to populate the desired collection of objects based on a condition, which might be:

```
if(!model.getName().equals("someName")) {
    list.add(model);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, once again, thank you Alex, you're the best!