# Java - How to get all city names (no duplicate) (Firestore)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi and please help me again. I have this like in docs:

```
cities
 \
  - id_number
        \
         - "population": 860000
        \
         - "name": San Francisco
 \
  - id_number
        \
         - "population": 3900000
        \
         - "name": Los Angeles
```

But if I have again Los Angeles?

```
 \
  - id_number
        \
         - "population": 3900000
        \
         - "name": Los Angeles
```

I can get all city:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(); //Duplicates
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document != null) {
                    String name = document.getString("name");
                    names.add(name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But names has duplicate. How to fix?

Comment: Just answered a similar question a few hours ago. Chould not mark as a duplicate, because it has no accepted answer yet. So please check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53147956/duplicate-data-when-i-merge-firestore-queries/53149644#53149644)**  out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have anything like "select distinct" in SQL.  If you want a list of unique strings from some field in a collection, you'll have to either query all the documents in the collection and count them in the client (as you are now), or store the list elsewhere in your database, probably another collection, and keep that up to date.

Comment: You say I need have 2 collection? One with all and one with no duplicate or?

Comment: I would make a collection with no duplicates, if that's what you query must load while minimizing the cost.